# Why Angular 6 component not routed in a lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

After hours, and many refactoring, i don't understand why a path in a lazy loaded routing module doesn't run as expected.

Schematically i have a routing module at the top of my app, that load a dashboard module :

```
  ...
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: '@app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  ...
```

DashboardModule imports DashBoardRoutingModule that is defined as :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      {path: 'shops', component: ShopListComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

I expected that a http://localhost/dashboard/shops will load ShopListComponent but... not at all...

I read some posts relative to this behaviour, but even the component was not inside the module himself, or... demos limit to one route...

What i'm missing ? Checked all my imports and declarations...

Thx

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Nothing... just fallback route (i.e /dashboard)

Comment: Can you try `loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'` instead of `loadChildren: '@app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'`

Comment: Same thing... The code of the button that will load the component :
    <a mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/dashboard/shops">{{ option.content.title }}</a>

Comment: ... if i inspect the console... nothing is loaded, network tab is empty when i click on the button... but browser indicates http://localhost:4200/dashboard/shops

Comment: Can you provide a little stackblitz?

Comment: https://angular-p1m2qj.stackblitz.io if u want to take an eye

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184882/discussion-between-jodandelion-and-jean-luc-aubert).

Comment: you need to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet> ` in your DashboardComponent

Answer (score 0):

In hello component you are trying this:

```
<a routerLink="/shops">Boutiques</a>
```

The path should be:

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard/shops">Boutiques</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

We found out that the problem was a missing `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the lazy loaded module.